# Bluetooth gamepad via Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit BLE

Tags: bluetooth, adafruit, joystick

I'm trying to build a Bluetooth-enabled gamepad out of an old Playstation 1 controller, using an Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit BLE.

I've programmed the board as a Keyboard HID and everything works: the controller button presses trigger keyboard presses through the Feather. However, treating the controller as a keyboard means I get no analog joystick support.

The Feather M0 supports a [Gamepad HID mode](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-bluefruit-le/ble-services#at-plus-blehidgamepad-14-44), but it's limited to 8 buttons and one joystick (but not analog), which is obviously not enough for a Playstation 1 controller.

I'm a bit stumped here: do I have any way of registering the BLE as a gamepad, to enable analog support, but with as many buttons as I need and two joysticks?

[My code so far, on GitHub.](https://github.com/monovertex/psx-bluetooth-controller)

Comment: how does it matter, if the joystick is analog? you have a mcu with analog pins. read the joystick, convert the values and send them. or am I missing something here?

Comment: It seems that adafruits firmware [doesn't support/implement that](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?t=51105#p258148).

Comment: @Juraj he means there is only D-pad support. So only left right up down (on or off).

Comment: @Gerben, thank you for the explanation. it is not about analog. joystick is a different HID profile then gamepad

Comment: and the joystick HID profile is not supported over (nRF52?) BLE. (there are really two M0 ARM MCUs on this board?)

Comment: @Juraj, my issue is sending data over in the correct manner, not reading it from the pins. But still, since joystick HID is not supported over this chip, it seems like I'm out of luck.

Comment: @Gerben, that info seems to be for the EZ-Key, not the Feather M0.

Comment: Adafruit has the same AT firmware in all Bluefruits

Comment: @Juraj, argh, I see. I'll try to map it as the mouse then, if the Feather will let me send both keyboard and mouse data. Thanks for the help!